# ASP.NET Membership Access to Network Resource

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I am using ASP.NET membership to control access to my application. Several pages in my application require read access to files on a network share (set up as an IIS Virtual Directory). Without membership, I just use impersonation to access the network share using a single predefined account. However, when using membership, how do I gain access to the network share with all of my "members"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

covered for a custom provider [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833810/asp-net-membership-provider-impersonation), probably easy enough to do for yours as well.

Answer (score 0):

Inherit built-in provider and implement impersonation inside